# Python, Deleting oldest 2000 files if a Windows10 folder contains more than 10000 files

Tags: python, directory

I know that in NTFS there could be 4,294,967,295 files in a single folder, and these are a lot, however I would control in some way this number of files in a folder (in my situation d:/screen/work/) where are saved 60 images per minute.
How could I do this using Python ? I was able to find a solution (below) only to remove older files (older than 7 days in the code below)
but no idea how to remove latest "n" oldest files (e.g. 2000) if folder contains more than "y" files (e.g. 10000).

```
from pathlib import Path
import arrow
import os
import sys
    filesPath = r"d:/screen/work/"
    criticalTime = arrow.now().shift(hours=+5).shift(days=-7)
    for item in Path(filesPath).glob('*'):
        if item.is_file():
            itemTime = arrow.get(item.stat().st_mtime)
            if itemTime < criticalTime:
                os.remove(str(item.absolute()))
                print(str(item.absolute()))
                pass
```

Comment: You could potentially save all filenames and creation dates to a `dict` then sort that dict and delete your lowest `n` values

Comment: Python code for [remove oldest files in a directory, only a defined count of them remains](http://www.henrykoch.de/en/python-remove-oldest-files-in-a-directory-only-a-defined-count-of-them-remains)

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Can you be more specific? You clearly know how to remove files, and it seems you're able to find when the file was created. Do you not know how to sort? Also, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy solution for that would be simple by creating a new `dict` and adding your `item.absolute()` and `itemTime.timestamp` as key value pairs

```
x[str(item.absolute())] = itemTime.timestamp
```

Then sorting it by values,

```
items_sorted = {k: v for k, v in sorted(x.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])}
```

and iterating through the first `len(dict)-n` values

```
from pathlib import Path
from itertools import islice
import arrow
import os
import sys

x = {}
n = 10

filesPath = r"d:/screen/work/"
criticalTime = arrow.now().shift(hours=+5).shift(days=-7)
for item in Path(filesPath).glob('*'):
    if item.is_file():
        itemTime = arrow.get(item.stat().st_mtime)
        if itemTime < criticalTime:
            x[str(item.absolute())] = itemTime.timestamp


items_sorted = {k: v for k, v in sorted(x.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])}

for path, itemTime in islice(items_sorted.items(), len(x)-n):
    os.remove(str(item.absolute()))
    print(path)
```

Additionally, this solution won't scale well on a very large number of files. Sorting the whole dict could be time consuming and inefficient but a better approach would be much more complex

Comment: it works however I do not understand how can I set this  "if folder contains more than "y" files (e.g. 10000)" in your code.

Comment: I didn't add that to the code. You'd probably want to add a counter and incrementing it below your `if item.is_file():` statement